# Assigning char array value to char

Tags: java, arrays, char

(in Java)
I am trying to take a value out of my char array

```
 char[] abc = {'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f'};
```

and assign it to a single char

```
 char currentChar = abc.[0];
```

and then ideally, I would replace 0 with and i for a for loop. Eclipse says

"The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Class"

How would I get variable currentChar to be equal to the character a ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be

```
char currentChar = abc[0];
```

Comment: Thanks! This is my accepted answer, but I can't accept it for 12 more minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
 char currentChar = abc[0];
```

when you are doing `abc.`, it means its expecting class or object because of dot

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is just wrong - there doesn't have to a dot.

Right would be:

```
char currentChar = abc[0];
```